# limits and continuity proof for polynomial of odd degree

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

Show that any polynomial of odd degree has at least one real root.

I think you have to use the Intermediate Value Theorem:  $\exists k$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, $\ni f(c) = k$

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate value theorem helps, if you can show that polynomials of odd degree take on arbitrarily large positive and negative values.